# ImageView in HorizontalScrollView has wrong aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to display a photo with so that it fills the display vertically, and is scrollable horizontally. My photos are of arbitrary dimensions, *but always in landscape aspect ratio*.

I placed an `ImageView` inside a `HorizonalScrollView`, and it almost works, except the aspect ratio is off. The `ImageView` is resized to fit exactly vertically, but the image is horizontally stretched or compressed.

**I've tried every combination of values for `scaleType` and `adjustViewBounds`**, and nothing works.

Can it be done with pure XML or do I have to resize my views in Java?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/panoramic_1" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

It scales in X and Y independently, so that imageview matches the maximum visible width and height.

Change to:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

This will keep the original aspect.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work. With centerInside, the aspect ratio is correct, but the image doesn't fill the ScrollView. BTW I've tried every value for scaleType and none of them work for me. :(  The rendered image is either the wrong size or the wrong aspect ratio.